# How To Restart IIS without Admin Rights in C#

Tags: c#, iis, admin-rights

What code do I need for a C# application to restart the user's IIS while the user does not have Admin rights?

Comment: Do you need to restart IIS or do you need to restart the application? In the first case, I don't think you can do it without admin rights (with good reason). In the second case: touch web.config.

Comment: @GrimaceofDespair: Just restart IIS

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible through code alone (and if it was, it'd be an exploit.)

You'd need to write a daemon that ran as a privileged user that accepted restart commands from unprivileged sources, say by checking for the existence of a lockfile or similar, or accepting commands over a socket, and then restarted the server accordingly.

Which would be a serious security risk, still, but whatever floats your boat.

It still might be better to think hard about why you want to do this. I think you'll find that whatever criteria prevent you from making the relevant user an IIS admin are excellent arguments for why the user shouldn't be rebooting IIS either.

Comment: This might be my answer, could you elaborate on how to write a daemon that does this? Examples or whatnot

Comment: IIS runs as a Windows service, so I should think that the lowest common denominator - issuing NET STOP/NET START shell commands as outlined below should be sufficient. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236166

Comment: I'd like to reiterate, though, that this is probably not a good solution to your problem, whatever it is.